# Deploying on azure with create-react-app

Tags: git, azure, reactjs, react-router

I am using create-react-app for developing my React app. Now I want to publish the bundle on the cloud. So I did:

```
npm run build
```

it created a `build` folder where I initialized a repo:

```
git init
```

then added the origin

```
git remote add origin https://mysiteonazure.com/app.git
```

finally committed and pushed the files. So I was able to view my app. The problem emerged when I wanted to navigate using URLs, so moving to:

```
http://mysiteonazure.com/login
```

did not work.

So I came to the following article [Deploying create-react-app on Microsoft Azure](https://medium.com/@to_pe/deploying-create-react-app-on-microsoft-azure-c0f6686a4321#.hnk3ufs1z)

So my build had:

```
build-azure
|_.git
|_static
|_asset-manifest-json
|_favicon.ico
|_index.html
```

And now I added `web.config`

```
build-azure
|_.git
|_static
|_asset-manifest-json
|_favicon.ico
|_index.html
|_web.config
```

With:

```
<?xml version=”1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name=”React Routes” stopProcessing=”true”>
 <match url=”.*” />
 <conditions logicalGrouping=”MatchAll”>
 <add input=”{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=”IsFile” negate=”true” />
 <add input=”{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=”IsDirectory” negate=”true” />
 <add input=”{REQUEST_URI}” pattern=”^/(api)” negate=”true” />
 </conditions>
 <action type=”Rewrite” url=”/” />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But now when I go to the main page: `http://mypage.azurewebsite.net` I get:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

How can I solve this problem? Or, how can I publish my app correctly?

Comment: Can you see the logs in Kudu?

Comment: What is in your web.config file?

Comment: @MichalCumpl I Updated my post with the `web.config`. Yes I have access to the Kudu's logs, what kind of info do you need?

Comment: Well, you say there is a internal server error and it would be nice to see the details... but you are deploying a static app without any server-side logic so the problem is probably in your web.config. Can you remove the whole rewrite section and try again?

Comment: I removed all the rewrite section and it does not worked, it keeps showing the same message :-\

Comment: I updated my app settings and now I have detailed info: `The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`

Comment: Ok, from that message I returned to the first `web.config` (with the rewrite rules) and it says: `Configuration file is not well-formed XML`

Comment: Can you please also share a list of files on the webapp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the detailed information, the problem was the quotes, I copied the `web.config` from the given source, and it had other quotes, so the real `web.config` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: where is the web.config supposed to go? which folder? thanks!

Comment: @John-Luke Laue - I put it in the public folder of the react app and that seemed to work fine. Routes worked ok on azure after I added it. I found this blog helpful in researching this issue: https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-1ied